# ¿Cómo consigo consultar datos específicos de una tabla de sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una base de datos que es de un programa para administrar cuentas personales. La tabla que tengo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se dan cuenta, el pago con el ID '1004' está asociado por el campo "CodMovimiento" al Id '1002'. Es decir es el 2do pago del movimiento con ID '1002'. Necesito traer los datos de los gastos, hechos en más de 1 cuota, pero que sean solo los últimos hechos(no se si me explico). En este ejemplo, los que tendría que traer serían el ID '1004' y el ID '1003'. Pero no logro traer todos los movimientos que tengan estas condiciones:

PagoFinalizado = 'No',

NumCuotasPagas < CantCuotas,

y que el campo "NumCuotasPagas" sea el último movimiento registrado de cada pago asociado.

**Es decir, que me traiga todos los movimientos de los últimos pagos de gastos hechos en cuotas.**

**¿Alguna aiudita para calmar mi frustración?**
**¿O alguna otra solución que funcione más eficientemente para lo que intento hacer?**

Pd: Espero haberme hecho entender.

Comment: Hola. La pregunta no se entiende y creo que es debido a que el mismo modelo de datos es confuso. Parecería que quieres manejar una lógica donde deberían intervenir varias tablas usando una sola tabla. Quizá ayude que intentes explicar lo que debe hacer tu programa, olvidándote por el momento  de como tienes estructurada la tabla actualmente.

Comment: Es un administrador de cuentas. Se tienen que registrar los distintos gastos, sueldo laboral, o cualquier otro movimiento que se haga, al estilo de una cuenta bancaria.

Comment: Lo que necesito es traer los pagos restantes de los gastos hechos en más de 1 pago. Por ejemplo. Compro 1 auto en 6 cuotas y lo registro en el programa. El mes siguiente necesito que me muestre la cuota N° 2 de esa compra para poder registrarla cuando haga el pago y el mes siguiente la N° 3 y así sucesivamente. Pero necesito traer el siguiente cuota de todos las compras o gastos hechos en más de 1 cuota.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para identificar al último pago, primero hay que definir cual es. Lo más sencillo es mediante la función ROW_NUMBER. Puesto que su resultado no puede ser usado directamente en el WHERE, necesitamos una CTE o subconsulta para poder hacer referencia al mismo. Dejo un ejemplo sencillo que podría funcionar.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ISNULL( CodMovimiento, ID) ORDER BY NumCuotasPagas DESC) rn
    FROM Tabla
    WHERE PagoFinalizado = 'No'
    AND NumCuotasPagas < CantCuotas
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: En la última línea me da error en "rn = 1". ¿Habría algo que falta especificar? Ejecutando la consulta que está dentro del paréntesis, me trae todos los movimientos y agrega esa columna extra enumerando las cuotas que existen al momento.

Comment: Perdón, fue un error al copiar y pegar, olvidé cambiar el nombre de la tabla por el de la CTE.

Comment: Ah no, ahí lo vi bien, y lo habías escrito bien, yo estaba poniendo al último la tabla de la base que yo tengo por eso daba error. Sos un genio. Hace exactamente lo que necesito. Grande!!!!! Gracias!!!

Comment: No, lo que pasa es que edité la respuesta para corregir el error.